# ui-mask and ngpattern not working for phone number

Tags: html, angularjs, regex, angular-ui, angularjs-ui-utils

I am trying to mask a number in format xxx-xxx-xxxx and trying to make sure that the the phone number starts from any digit except 0 and 1

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{ 'error' : editForm.homePhone.$invalid && editForm.$dirty }">
                    <label class="label" for="homePhone">Home Phone</label>
                    <input  name="homePhone"                              
                           data-ng-model="edit.HomePhoneNumber"
                           required
                           ng-pattern="/^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/"
                           ui-mask="999-999-9999" ui-mask-placeholder />
                    <span>{{editForm.homePhone}}</span>
                    <span class="error-message field-validation" data-ng-show="editForm.homePhone.$invalid && editForm.homePhone.$dirty">
                        Phone number must be in the format xxx-xxx-xxxx
                    </span>
                </div>
```

It always says number as invalid. I tried to print editForm.homePhone

I did check all posts on stackoverflow. Tried them, but no go.
Not sure what is incorrect?

I am using ui-utils.js - v0.1.1 for ui-mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be ui-utils.js v0.1.1

I included ui-mask directly and its working correctly: http://codepen.io/emed/pen/GqqmKW

```
(tested with angular 1.5.5 and ui-mask 1.8.5)
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask